# linear algebra - basis for a subspace given unspecified vectors and condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you are given the following (contrived example):

> = {v ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup> | 10v<sub>1</sub> + 4v<sub>2</sub> - 2v<sub>3</sub> = 0}

How would you find the basis for a problem like this? I am confused because unlike questions [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595515/finding-the-basis-of-a-subspace-given-a-subspace-containing-conditions), Y is not in the format (1,2,...,).

I know at some point I must show linear independence.

Is the next step creating an augmented 3x3 matrix with each vector scaled by their respective scalar?

Comment: Hint: This is one equation in three unknowns. Solve for one variable and move from there.

Comment: Is it such a big different if you write your vector as $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ instead of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos my understanding was that each v denoted different vectors--not the components of a single vector. Am I misunderstanding notation?

Comment: The *numbers* $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are such that $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

Answer (score 1):

One way of finding a basis is to pick a value for $v_1$ and then pick values for $v_2, v_3$ that make the equation true.

Let $v_1=1, v_2=1, v_3=7$. Then $(1, 1, 7)\in Y$. Now let $v_1=1, v_2=2, v_3=9$. Then $(1, 2, 9)\in Y$. Because $Y\subset R^3$, it can only have at most $3$ linearly independent vectors as its basis. But the vector $(1, 0, 0)\notin Y$ and thus $Y$ is not $3$ dimensional as if it had $3$ basis vectors, then $Y$ would be $R^3$ itself.

Since we have found two linearly independent vectors $(1, 1, 7), (1, 2, 9)$ that are both in $Y$, they are automatically a basis of $Y$ as $Y$ can't be $3$ dimensional.